# How to load data from plist without changing the order

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, ordereddictionary

I want to load NSDictionary from the following plist file, without changing the order of it.
[image: Plist file]
This plist file is [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/test.plist).
I have researched many things, and I found [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary) and [M13OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary).
First, I tried NSDictionary (I know it fails)

```
- (void)testNSDictionary {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
```

Then I got the following log:

```
{
    G =     {
        R =         {
            H = "";
            S = "";
        };
        V =         {
            T = "";
        };
    };
    S =     {
        B =         {
            L = "";
        };
        O =         {
            K = "";
            L = "";
        };
        V =         {
            T = "";
        };
    };
}
```

This is completely different order from the original plist file! (I know)
I think this is alphabetical order.
Next, I tried OrderedDictionary with the following code:

```
#import "OrderedDictionary.h"
- (void)testOrderedDictionary {
    OrderedDictionary *dictionary = [OrderedDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
```

Then I got the following log:

```
{
    G =     {
        R =         {
            H = "";
            S = "";
        };
        V =         {
            T = "";
        };
    };
    S =     {
        B =         {
            L = "";
        };
        O =         {
            K = "";
            L = "";
        };
        V =         {
            T = "";
        };
    };
}
```

Huh? This is the same result as NSDictionary.
Finally, I tried M13OrderedDictionary with the following code.

```
#import "M13OrderedDictionary.h"
- (void)testM13OrderedDictionary {
    M13OrderedDictionary *dictionary = [M13OrderedDictionary orderedDictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
```

Then I got the following log:

```
{
}
```

Nothing returned. I don't understand what is going on.
I would like to know how I can correctly use OrderedDictionary and M13OrderedDictionary. If they are outdated, I want to know the alternative way to parse plist file into NSDictionary or NSArray or something.

Note: I don't want to change plist file, because this format is the best for me.

Comment: How are you determining that the keys are out of order? You decide what order to access the keys in the NSDictionary. If you're looking to use a set with a definitive order, use NSArray, not NSDictionary.

Comment: I know NSArray can save the order, but it can't possess the name of NSArray itself. For example in this case, the deepest layer T,S,H,T,L,K,L can be contained by NSArray, but others can't. Is it possible to include array name itself in NSArray plist?

Comment: Are you aware of ``NSXMLDocument``? It can be used to load any correctly formatted xml document (plists included) in a single line, with an API very similar to to that of ``NSDictionary`` and ``NSArray`` (``init(URL:...``). Once you've got this document in memory, you can iterate through its elements to construct your ordered dictionary. Or you could just leave it as an ``NSXMLDocument`` instance, and harness the power of *xPath* to parse it.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know NSXMLDocument! It seems very meaningful to try it.

Comment: `NSXMLDocument` isn't available for iOS.

Comment: Then alternatively I will use NSXMLParser for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the script above has some bugs.
I contacted with the developer of OrderedDictionary and finally he made the importing and exporting function.
[OrderedDictionary v1.4](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary/releases) can import OrderedDictionary data from plist file(xml format only).

I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

An OrderedDictionary can't live in a plist file. Well, it can in a sense, but not in the plist file you are showing. Plist files know about NSArray, NSDictionary, and a few other elementary classes that can be elements of those — and that's all. Your plist file consists of an NSDictionary, not an OrderedDictionary. So you are just going to get back an ordinary NSDictionary when you load it.

> Note: I don't want to change plist file, because this format is the best for me

Fine. But then you are going to be loading an ordinary NSDictionary.

Comment: Thanks. If I use xml file not plist file, is it possible to convert xml data into nsarray or nsdictionary?

Comment: Absolutely! You will have to do the converting. But that is a great idea. Of course, you could argue that plist _is_ an xml file, so you could keep your current format — but again, you will have to do all the parsing yourself.

Comment: Ok, but is there anyone who has already succeeded in parsing plist file? If nobody has done it, I will try and post it here.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but we are now well outside the scope of what you originally asked. Your question was why you weren't able to get an OrderedDictionary using `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`. As for OrderedDictionary `initWithContentsOfFile`, it works only if that is how you saved the first place, and of course you did not — you are starting with a normal hand-made plist.

Comment: I will try to save plist file using initWithContentsOfFile, and check the difference between the saved file and my original plist.

Comment: I tried to save plist file with `writeToData` method, but it is not defined in OrderedDictionary. Then I used NSKeyedArchiver to save plist file as NSData, and I got [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/test2.plist). This seems very complicated format.

Comment: It's called `writeToFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeeded in parsing my plist file using OrderedDictionary. This is my code:
[ParserDelegate.h]

```
@interface ParserDelegate : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
@end
```

[ParserDelegate.m]

```
#import "ParserDelegate.h"
#import "OrderedDictionary.h"
@interface ParserDelegate()
@end

@implementation ParserDelegate {
    BOOL isDict;
    BOOL isKey;
    BOOL isString;
    BOOL stringExists;
    int layer;
    int arrayNum;
    MutableOrderedDictionary *parsedDictionary;
    MutableOrderedDictionary *tempDictionary;
    MutableOrderedDictionary *tempTempDictionary;
    NSMutableArray *keysArray;
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Started parsing plist file...");
    isKey = NO;
    layer = 0;
    arrayNum = 0;
    parsedDictionary = [[MutableOrderedDictionary alloc] init];
    tempDictionary = [[MutableOrderedDictionary alloc] init];
    tempTempDictionary = [[MutableOrderedDictionary alloc] init];
    keysArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"dict"]) {
        isDict = YES;
        layer++;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"key"]) {
        isKey = YES;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        isString = YES;
        stringExists = NO;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (isDict) {
        if ([tempDictionary count] != 0) {
            [tempDictionary removeAllObjects];
        }
        isDict = NO;
    }
    if (isKey) {
        [keysArray addObject:string];
        arrayNum++;
    }
    if (isString) {
        tempDictionary[[keysArray objectAtIndex:[keysArray count] - 1]] = string;
        stringExists = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"dict"]) {
        layer--;
        if (layer == 2) {
            tempTempDictionary[[keysArray objectAtIndex:[keysArray count] - [tempDictionary count] - 1]] = [tempDictionary copy];
        } else if (layer == 1) {
            parsedDictionary[[keysArray objectAtIndex:[keysArray count] - arrayNum]] = [tempTempDictionary copy];
            [tempTempDictionary removeAllObjects];
            arrayNum = 0;
        }
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"key"]) {
        isKey = NO;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        if (!stringExists) {
            tempDictionary[[keysArray objectAtIndex:[keysArray count] - 1]] = @"";
        }
        isString = NO;
    }
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Finished parsing!");
    NSLog(@"%@",[parsedDictionary description]);
}

@end
```

I'm sorry that this script supports only my plist file, so other format plist files can't be parsed by this.

Usage:

```
ParserDelegate *parserDelegate = [[ParserDelegate alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser.delegate = parserDelegate;
[parser parse];
```